# Convert format date string to datetime using T-SQL in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime

How can I convert this format to datetime? I'm using SQL Server 2008.

The string can be `d/m/aaaa` or `dd/m/dddd` or `d/mm/aaaa` or `dd/mm/aaaa` and I need to convert these formats to `datetime`. Any idea?

Comment: CONVERT(datetime, <yourstring>, 103)  ?

Comment: Its works! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CONVERT()` as:

```
DECLARE @S1 VARCHAR(20) = '1-1-2017';
DECLARE @S2 VARCHAR(20) = '11/1/2017';
DECLARE @S3 VARCHAR(20) = '1/11/2017';
DECLARE @S4 VARCHAR(20) = '11/11/2017';


SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, @S1 , 104) AS S1,
       CONVERT(DATETIME, @S2 , 104) AS S2,
       CONVERT(DATETIME, @S3 , 104) AS S3,
       CONVERT(DATETIME, @S4 , 104) AS S4;
```

Result:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|         S1          |         S2          |         S3          |         S4          |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 01.01.2017 00:00:00 | 11.01.2017 00:00:00 | 01.11.2017 00:00:00 | 11.11.2017 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: It works, but why do you have `104` as a parameter? It doesn't make sense to me, and it works without this additional parameter as well.